# Finding the coordinates of a color in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to make a bot to play a game. Players all have the same colors, and I have found how to find RGB values on the screen. The code I use looks like this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class mouseBot{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
        Rectangle captureSize = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = robot.createScreenCapture(captureSize);

        int color = image.getRGB(x, y);

        int  red = (color & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
        int  green = (color & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
        int  blue = color & 0x000000ff;
    }
}
```

How would I start finding a specific color. In this case, I would like to find the color rgb(100, 74, 211) and save its coords as an X and Y `int` value

Comment: probably better of using `getRGB(int startX, int startY, int w, int h, int[] rgbArray, int offset, int scansize)` So you can get chunks of the pixels in the image and search through that array

Comment: you are showing some code that has been put together